# Why when breakpoint is present in my solution, the browser launched by the Javascript Debugger never actually resolve the page?

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints

I found many post where breakpoint are not being it, but that is not the problem, the page simply never load. In the network tab, it says the initial request is pending and never complete.

If I open the same url on an other tabs in the same chrome, I have the same behavior but if I open the page on an other chrome window (off course debugging won't work from there, unless I change de configuration to attach with some more settings) it does load. Which suggest that server is correctly running.

The chrome launched by the debugging is definately somewhat isolated to the normal installation (should be the default as I don't think ive made any changes) which would explain the behavior only in this context.

However I do not know what can I look for this resolve this issue. This used to work and suddently stop working, I can't says if due to a minor change in the configuration or update for the extention.

I have tried re-installing vscode, running vscode with --disable-extensions flag, without any success.

I have not seen any information related to this in the documentation here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging

launch.json for reference

```
{
      "name": "client",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:5000/app/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/angular-client"
}
```

I am running the `ng build --deploy-url '/app/' --base-href '/app/' --output-path` explaining the extra `/app` in the launch setting, this is an Angular App if relevant, back-end is .net core.

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I installed "Visual Code Insiders" version 1.77 and the problem doesn't exist there.

This issue happens on different workstations and different projects.